# Changing a user's default shell

Tags: linux, bash, shell, c

I have created a simple C shell on my local Linux server. I am trying to learn how to change the default shell of another user (`bob`) to be this new C shell that I have created.

Is it possible to changing the default shell of my user `bob` so that when I log in as him, he will be using the C shell I made?

Do I need to add the `.C` file into the `/bin/bash` folder and then changing the starting shell for `bob` in my root account?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

As root, you can set a user's shell to whatever you like with `chsh` or any other method (e.g. editing `/etc/passwd` with `vipw`), just remember to use the full pathname to the executable.

If you want a user to be able to choose it as their shell with `chsh`, you first have to add it to `/etc/shells`, which is a list of full pathnames of valid shells.

You can't change another user's shell unless you are root, you can only change your own shell.

Comment: If I am logged in as user1 where the .c file is, how would I go about moving that to /etc/shell?

Comment: can only be added to `/etc/shells` as root.  e.g. with `su` or `sudo`.

Comment: @Hayes121 `/etc/shells` is a file that lists all available shells. You would need to edit that file as root and add `/path/to/your/shell` to it.

Comment: I have moved the shell into /etc/shell, so now when I have the executable C file in /etc/shell, path to file name is now /etc/shell/shell1 but when I try 'chsh -s /etc/shell/shell bob' I get an error an error saying /etc/shell/shell1 isnt a directory

Comment: that makes no sense.  you add the full path to your shell (e.g. `/usr/local/bin/myfabulousshell`) to the list of valid shells in `/etc/shells`

Comment: and you can't change another user's shell unless you are root.  and if you are root, you can set it to anything whether it is listed in `/etc/shells` or not